# MonoTouch CorePlot 1.1 binding error

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, core-plot

The monotouch [bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/CorePlot) for CorePlot are stuck to version 0.9, while the library has now reached [version 1.1](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/):

I'm trying to update the [makefile](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/CorePlot/binding/Makefile) by myself, but it doesn't work.

I've changed the following line in the makefile:

```
VERSION=0.9
```

with:

```
VERSION=1.1
```

And then executed the make. It created the CorePlotiOS.dll 1.1 library fine, but when I add those to my project in Monodevelop, replacing the old CorePlotiOS.dll 0.9, something goes wrong. In the simulator everything seems ok, but when I run the app on the iPhone I get the following error and then a crash:

```
Wrapper type 'MonoTouch.CorePlot.CPTPlainBlackTheme' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'CPTPlainBlackTheme'.
```

There was no such error when using the 0.9 dll. Is there something I'm missing? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that is because CorePlot 1.1 added/amended new properties / methods etc.

You'll need to update [coreplot.cs](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/CorePlot/binding/coreplot.cs), [enums.cs](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/CorePlot/binding/enums.cs) and [extras.cs](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/CorePlot/binding/extras.cs) to accurately reflect the changes mades from 0.9 to 1.1